# Providing a default implementation for an overriden UIViewController method, but only if the controller conforms to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocol-oriented

In my app I've had a lot of boilerplate code I had to write whenever there was a UITableView in some controller. To eliminate it, I created a **BaseTableViewController** that implements some repeatedly used `UITableDataSource` operations like `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` and `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. In `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, my BaseTableViewController retrieves the actual number of rows in a section from another method (let's call it `rowCount(inSection:)`) and performs some computations using it, then returns the result to the delegating caller. Each class subclassing the BaseTableViewController must override the `rowCount(inSection:)` method and return its proper row count in a given section (BaseTableViewController itself returns 0 in its default implementation).

Now, some of my table view controllers support paging for displayed records - when the users scrolls the table view to its last row, next batch of rows is retrieved from the network. Trying to make things more protocol-oriented, I created a protocol for pageable controllers:

```
protocol Pageable: class {
    associatedtype DataType
    var pages: [[DataType]] { get set } // Each page is an array of elements, hence the table in a table
    func loadNextPage()
}
```

If a controller is `Pageable`, the `rowCount(inSection:)` methods always looks like this:

```
override func rowCount(inSection: Int) -> Int {
    return self.pages[section].count
}
```

This is tedious, because every BaseTableViewController descendant that is also Pageable must have this exact implementation, which violates DRY.

I cannot add a default implementation in a protocol extension for `Pageable`, because the controller already has its own implementation inherited from BaseTableViewController.

I came up with a solution, but I don't like it: I could create a PageableTableViewController (a subclass of BaseTableViewController) that provides its own overriden implementation of `rowCount(inSection:)`, but that's not very protocol-oriented. I also tried to move the `rowCount(inSection:)` method to a protocol, but if I make all descendants of BaseTableViewController to conform to that protocol with a protocol extension, extending `Pageable` to implement the method won't work.

How would I create a mechanism where all subclasses of `BaseTableViewController` would be able to override the `rowCount(inSection:)` method, but when they're `Pageable`, they share a default implementation of it that's (possibly) placed in a Pageable protocol extension?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you are looking for with protocol extensions. the extension will apply just in case the object implementing the protocol is actually an UIViewController.

```
protocol something {
    func method()
}
extension something where Self: UIViewController {
    func method() {
        //Default implementation
    }
}
```